# How to compare percentage change in year by only months entered?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working in Google Spreadsheets trying to compare two years of data for each month.

```
year jan  feb  mar  apr  may  etc
2012   4    3    5    6    4    3
2013   2    4    5
```

I want to be able to compare the data I have so far because if I don't have enough data, then the comparison will not be accurate until all of the months are complete.

How do I compare 2013's jan,feb,march to 2012's jan,feb,march and have it dynamically adjust?

For instance, if I input april, have it compare jan-april of 2012 as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'compare'? I'd compare them by just looking at them side by side but I suspect you want something more procedural. What should the comparison show, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This question might be better suited to  http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Moob, to be more clear.  I'd like to compare it as a percentage change from the previous year.  As you can see, if I were to compare year 2013 to 2012 for a percentage change, it would be a negative number since 2013 is not complete yet.  Is there a way to calculate the percentage change for the months I have so far to the same months of the previous year? i.e. jan-march of 2013 to jan-march of 2012? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",SUM($B3:B3)/SUM($B2:B2)-1)
```

in B4 and copy across to suit.

Yes, in this case the formula works (or not!) the same in Excel and Google Docs.